# Useage of qgis core plugin in another plugin

Tags: interpolation, postgis, qgis

I am trying to develop a plugin in QGIS where import data as points, I would than like to interpolate the points to polygon and then run an analyse on the polygons.

It works perfectly if I stop my plugin, use the qgis core tool "Interpolate" and then run my analyse. But is there any way that I can import the Interpolate tool and feed the tool my self? Something like:

```
from qgis.core.??SOMETHING?? import interpolate

interpolate(InterpolateLayer, InterpolateMethod, numberOfColumns, numbersOfRows etc. etc.)
```

Alternative if there is any method that I can use from postgis? I tried:

```
select st_delaunaytriangles(pos, 0.001, 1) into new_table from table_with_point_as_pos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out!

```
import processing
GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER = '%f,%f,%f,%f'% (min_lon, max_lon, min_lat , max_lat)
processing.runandload("grass:v.voronoi", path_and_file_name_point,False, False, GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER, -1, 0, 3, path_and_file_name_poly)
```

I had huge problems with getting the correct format for GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER. I had an extra space in the end which resulted in that no polygon file were created (`"= '%f, %f, %f, %f '%"` etc. instead of `"= '%f,%f,%f,%f'%"` etc.)

The only "problem" that remains now are that it takes rather long time to run the process with 100k+ points.